# JoinColumns behavior for queries

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to understand if I can effect the sql query constructed by eclipselink based on my domain object's (Organization) @JoinColumns on a self-referencing Parent field.

```
        @JoinColumns({
                @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID", referencedColumnName = "ORG_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
        })
        private Organization parent;
```

Reason for doing it is the query is faster when the join has both the parent_id and org_id.
Everything is fine until we try to query to find top-level organizations (Parent = null).  The generated query has parent_id is null and org_id is null... this doesn't give us what we need.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't guess why the query would be faster on a composite FK vs a FK with just the ID unless you don't have indexing on it, but this will affect plain old find operations on the Organization as well, wouldn't it? If you are trying to do a 'where org.parent is null' type query - the reason is that you've mapped these as both as foreign keys, so there is no other way for JPA to know only one of the columns is really what you want to check for. This might be more what you want to consider http://onpersistence.blogspot.com/2008/01/customizing-eclipselink-jpaorm.html

Comment: I had the same why-do-I-have-to-do-this question, since it is an indexed PK, but multiple left outer joins on "self" on a very large table are defeating the postgres optimizer without the addition of being able to slice it by another qualifier.   I'm going to check out the customizer, that could be a nice workaround.

Comment: fwiw, I was able to "fix" it by making a change to eclipselink to not add an IS NULL in the join when the field is not nullable, but I'd rather not have to do that.

Comment: Alternatively, you might map the "PARENT_ID" column as a basic mapping (insertable=false,updateable=false) and use it in the query for the is null check instead of the relationship. This will prevent the need to join the tables at all and let you keep your parent reference as it is (though I'd still look into the customizer on it). EclipseLink doesn't require you to actually map the field (you can add what it calls a query key on the column) but might be easier to add the property for testing.